# Android Studio: Gradle Sync issue: Unable to load class int

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-studio

Starting this evening, my project won't run.  "Make Project" works fine, everything compiles without incident, but when I try to run it in the Wear emulator, within seconds I get the following error in the Build Output window:

```
Unable to load class 'int'
int

Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)

Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.

Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.
```

In the Build Output window, if I click on "int", I get:

```
Could not load the value of field `val$unboxed` of `com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$32` 
bean found in field `list` of `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList` 
bean found in field `factories` of `com.google.gson.Gson` 
bean found in field `mGson` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.MessageReceiverImpl` 
bean found in field `messageReceiverImpl` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.SyncIssueReporterImpl` 
bean found in field `issueReporter` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.errors.DeprecationReporterImpl` 
bean found in field `deprecationReporter` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.ProjectServices` 
bean found in field `projectServices` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.VariantServicesImpl` 
bean found in field `variantServices` of `com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LayeredSourceDirectoriesImpl` 
bean found in field `lateAdditionsDelegates` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceDirectorySet` 
bean found in field `assets` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.DefaultAndroidSourceSet` 
bean found in field `androidTestSourceSet` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.DefaultConfigData` 
bean found in field `defaultConfigData` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.LegacyVariantInputManager` 
bean found in field `$tmp0` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.LegacyVariantInputManager$3` 
bean found in field `val$action` of `org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext$CurrentApplication$1` 
bean found in field `delegate` of `org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultCollectionCallbackActionDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction` 
bean found in field `actions` of `org.gradle.internal.ImmutableActionSet$SetWithFewActions` 
bean found in field `addActions` of `org.gradle.api.internal.collections.DefaultCollectionEventRegister` 
bean found in field `eventRegister` of `org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer` 
bean found in field `buildTypes` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ApplicationExtensionImpl$AgpDecorated` 
bean found in field `$extension` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.BootClasspathConfigImpl$1` 
bean found in field `isJava8Compatible` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.factory.BootClasspathConfigImpl` 
bean found in field `value` of `kotlin.InitializedLazyImpl` bean found in field `bootClasspathConfig$delegate` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.AppPlugin` 
bean found in field `this$0` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.plugins.BasePlugin$dslServices$2$1` 
bean found in field `versionedSdkLoaderServiceProvider` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.services.DslServicesImpl` 
bean found in field `dslServices` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PostProcessingBlock` 
bean found in field `_postProcessing` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType$AgpDecorated` 
bean found in field `buildTypeObj` of `com.android.build.gradle.internal.core.dsl.impl.features.AndroidResourcesDslInfoImpl` 
bean found in field `androidResourcesDsl` of `com.android.build.api.component.impl.features.AndroidResourcesCreationConfigImpl` 
bean found in field `value` of `kotlin.InitializedLazyImpl` 
bean found in field `androidResourcesCreationConfig$delegate` of `com.android.build.api.component.impl.AndroidTestImpl` 
bean found in field `androidTest` of `com.android.build.api.variant.impl.ApplicationVariantImpl` 
bean found in field `elements` of `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList$SerializedForm` 
bean found in field `components` of task `:wearApp:signingReport` of type `com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.SigningReportTask`.
BUILD FAILED in 956ms
Configuration cache entry stored with 961 problems.
```

I've deleted the caches ([UserDirectory]/gradle/caches and [ProjectDirectory]/.gradle/configuration-cache), and within Studio I've cleaned the build and invalidated caches; I've even tried rebooting the whole machine. I've tried upgrading Gradle from 8.2.0 to 8.4.0-alpha3. Nothing works.

I've searched online for a fix to this, but haven't found anything useful.

I should note that the only thing I did between when it worked and when it didn't was to add an "implementation" dependency to the build.gradle; when I tried running and got the error for the first time, I immediately deleted it.

Can somebody help me out? What would my next steps be?

Comment: Can you show your source code where the error occurs? Specifically, where is this happening: *Unable to load class 'int'*

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by running:

```
gradle signingReport --no-configuration-cache on windows.
```

On MacOS or linux, run:

```
./gradlew signingReport --no-configuration-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.  I uninstalled Android Studio and Gradle, deleted the ./gradle directory, rebooted, then reinstalled everything.  Something in gradle was corrupted.